# C# - when i try play my exe file i get security error message, what can i do?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, security, publish

i'm finish now project on C#
i working with vs2015
and when i try to extract exe file from visual studio i get file that work in my computer but if i try send to someone he get security error message.
im putting picture - this what happend when i try to play exe file.
its security error maybe because " unknown publisher ".
and i try to upload and download to my coputer and it's don't working,

[image]

Comment: Not a development question really. Windows doesn't recognize the file so he gets a warning... If he clicks more info, he can then choose to "run anyway"

Comment: yes i know, but my question is how can i fix it?

Comment: Fix what? It (the warning) is working exactly as expected and can be worked around (I told you how he can bypass it for example).

Comment: But i want publish and send the software and in this situation the user dont open this.

Comment: Your question needs a lot of work, then. This is not a forum for back and forth discussion but a Q&A site. You need to 1) Describe your problem more clearly, 2) Give steps of what you have done / tried, 3) state explicitly the current problem, issue or question.

Answer (score 2):

What's happening is Windows Smart Screen doesn't actually recognize the developing signature, so it just assumes it's un-trusted, and un-safe.

Comment: Is there a way to add a signature to fix it?

Comment: `Is there a way to add a signature to fix it?` Perhaps this is the question you meant to ask, although hopefully you put some effort into researching it first.

Comment: I checked this before and i added signature but it is not work..maybe have another way

Comment: @Idan So either post a new question or edit this one. Specify details about how you tried to create that signature and any results from that. Link to resources you used to add that sig.